# SketchUp -> Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, sketchup

I've been searching for a while for how to get a 3d model we built in SketchUp to be shown on a web page. I found three.js and saw that I could export it to a .dae and use the ColladaLoader to load it. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get anything to show up on my black canvas yet. (Using the latest three.js from the master branch, latest Chrome, latest OS X.)

Here's the gist of my code (inspired by http://jsfiddle.net/f17Lz5ux/):

```
  var camera, scene, renderer, my_model;

  init();

  function init() {
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 1000;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var loader = new ColladaLoader2();
    //var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

    loader.load('3d-model.dae', function(result) {
      my_model = result.scene;
      scene.add(prequel);
      animate();
    });

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    jQuery("#canvas").append(renderer.domElement);
    //document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    my_model.rotation.x += 0.01;
    my_model.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
```

Here's what shows up in the console when using the ColladaLoader from the three.js repo:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/screenshots.equityeats.com/rh1zz.png (the dev tools freeze up so I couldn't copy/paste)

I searched the open issues for three.js and found https://github.com/rmx/threejs-collada, but that doesn't work either. Here's what shows up in the console when using that collada loader:

```
ColladaLoader2 WARNING: Skipped element <asset>/<contributor>. Element is legal, but not handled by this loader.
ColladaLoader.js?body=1:7138 ColladaLoader2 WARNING: Skipped element <asset>/<created>. Element is legal, but not handled by this loader.
ColladaLoader.js?body=1:7138 ColladaLoader2 WARNING: Skipped element <asset>/<modified>. Element is legal, but not handled by this loader.
8ColladaLoader.js?body=1:7138 ColladaLoader2 WARNING: Skipped unknown element <library_visual_scenes>/<visual_scene>/<node>/<node>/<node>/<instance_node>.
76ColladaLoader.js?body=1:7138 ColladaLoader2 WARNING: Skipped unknown element <library_visual_scenes>/<visual_scene>/<node>/<node>/<instance_node>.
1112ColladaLoader.js?body=1:7138 ColladaLoader2 ERROR: Geometry primitive type lines not supported.
ColladaLoader.js?body=1:7138 ColladaLoader2 WARNING: Skipped unknown element <library_nodes>.
ColladaLoader.js?body=1:6103 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered uploading your model to the [3D warehouse](https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com) and then use the **Embed** function to show it on your own web page?

It offers both a **Thumbnail** view and a **3D viewer** with zoom, pan and rotate options.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the 3D Warehouse solution. Also, Sketchfab is a great website/service/tool for that. You can upload your SketchUp models to their website, and even add annotations, which becomes Scenes, of sorts. You can also embed the Sketchfab 3D model into a Facebook post!